# How can I configure the Header bar with redux state so that the header icon should be changed dynamically?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am going to implement header bar with notification icon. when the notification is received the notification icon of header bar should be changed into other notification icon. how can I implement it using redux? I think redux is the proper solution for it. but I'm not sure how can I connect react-navigation header with redux

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "...",
    headerRight: (
      <Image
        source={require("../../../assets/notification_grey.png")}
      />
    ),
  };
```

So when the new notification is received, then this right icon of Header should be updated to other icon(`notification_blue.png`)

Comment: Do you have any code you can share with us so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: @quicklikerabbit, I shared the code, pls check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new component for your header, connect that to Redux as you would do for any other component, and pass it to your navigator.

For example:

The Header component:

```js
import React from 'react'

class HeaderRight extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Show something about your notifications
    return <View>{this.props.notifications.length}</View>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  // Get your notifications from the Redux state
  notifications: state.something.notifications,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeaderRight)
```

The navigator:

```js
static navigationOptions = {
  title: "...",
  headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
}
```

You have other ways to pass your Header component to a navigator, this is just an example, [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options.html) you can find a few alternatives.

Comment: But I need to use native Header of react-navigation, not custom header. do you think it's possible?

Comment: You can use the same approach but override a single part of the header, for example, rather than override the full header, you can use headerLeft, headerRight, title, etc. Check the documentation for navigationOptions

Comment: Oh, yes! it works. just found some issues on other parts.